# Importing functions only in Python files

Tags: python, function, import, module

I'm a newbie, writing 2 functions in separate files (weather.py, TTS_phrase.py) in the same directory, to then use together:

```
def weather_now(my_town)
  [My code]
  return ("Sunny skies")

city = input("City Name : ")
print(weather_now(city))
```

and

```
def talk(text_to_convert)
  [My code].save(filename)
  print("Done")

t = input("What text would you like to convert to speech?\n")
talk(t)
```

They both work fine independently. When I create a new py file, import both functions ONLY, not the parts after it, it still seems to run the whole py file, not JUST the function.

```
import weather as w
import TTS_phrase as TTS

text1 = w.weather_now("London")
TTS.talk(text1)
```

The indents are correct. It's asking me for inputs and tries to save 2 files when I run this code. Am I doing something wrong? I'd really appreciate a steer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you must understand that whenever a file is imported the whole script must run! so you can make a check, and exclude code you dont run on execute like this:

```
def weather_now(my_town)
  [My code]
  return ("Sunny skies")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    city = input("City Name : ")
    print(weather_now(city))
```

and

```
def talk(text_to_convert)
  [My code].save(filename)
  print("Done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = input("What text would you like to convert to speech?\n")
    talk(t)
```

Comment: This does not address the import protocol, as OP requests.

Comment: Oh! Yes, it seems to be importing the whole script, hence asking me for inputs. I thought I could simply call ONLY the function as part of a script, without calling the whole script.

Comment: I added the "if __name__" sections, and they fixed it all. Sorry I haven't learnt about them or come across them yet. Thanks very much. It was driving me crazy (!)